# Error 1004 on formula

Tags: vba, excel, debugging

When I run this code, I repeatedly am getting error 1004

```
with activecell
.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Address & "," _
& ":" & "," & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Address & ")"
end with
```

Does anyone have an idea of where the issue is presenting itself?

Comment: You have an extra `:,` in there, you don't need that. Try `.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Address & ","  & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Address & ")"`

Comment: Is your active cell column A or column B? In that case, there is no cell at `.offset(0, -2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want

```
"=CONCATENATE(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Address & ","":""," & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Address & ")"
```

Because your current formula evaluates to  (with F4 selected)

```
=CONCATENATE($D$4,:,$E$4)
```

Which is wrong hence the error.

Try

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    With ActiveCell
        .Formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & .Offset(0, -2).Address & ","":""," & .Offset(0, -1).Address & ")"
    End With
End Sub
```

That has a formula which evaluates to

```
=CONCATENATE($D$4,":",$E$4)
```

This adds the missing `""` surrounding your `:`

Comment: also, since the `With ActiveCell` is being used, this can be improved by removing the future references to activecell inside the with block

Comment: Very true. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for the responds and answer. The reason I have the ":" is to put the colon between the two concatenates.

Comment: The syntax for concatenate is as at bottom of my answer. It uses "," not ":" .    I am guessing that holds true for some other locales but potentially some may use ";" .

Comment: Thank you but this is the formula i put directly into the cell without vba

=CONCATENATE(i233,":",p233)
if i233 = ABC and p233 has DEF

and it produces an answer like this ABC:DEF

Comment: Updated answer sorry

Comment: Works like a charm @QHarr Thank you so much.